# NSUserDefaults refuses to store NSString objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I've tried to hide my settings in a wrapper class, so configuration can get read and set via properties. But for an unknown reason the following setter doesn't save the value as expected:

```
- (void)setCountryCode:(NSString *)countryCode
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (countryCode) {
        [defaults setObject:@"CountryCode" forKey:countryCode];
    } else {
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"CountryCode"];
    }
    if (![defaults synchronize]) {
        ALog(@"Something unexpected went wrong. Wasn't able to save CountryCode to NSUserDefaults!"); // Never logged, since there doesn't seem to be an error.
    }
    _countryCode = countryCode;
}
```

But when trying to restore it, it always retrieves `nil`.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        _countryCode = [defaults objectForKey:@"CountryCode"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

What I've done wrong?

Comment: Include the method call also,where you set the value

Comment: The key and the object are in the wrong place. Try swapping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
[defaults setObject:@"CountryCode" forKey:countryCode];
```

I think you want to do this:

```
[defaults setObject:countryCode forKey:@"CountryCode"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're switching the parameters in `setObject:forKey:`. Try:

```
[defaults setObject:countryCode forKey:@"CountryCode"];
```